# Why is fortran wrapper needed in C programming?

Tags: c, fortran, wrapper, blas

I'm recently reading some source code in cBLAS, and something make me unclear. In many functions, a .c file calls Fortran Wrapper instead of writing the codes directly in the C file, like the following file:

```
/*
 * cblas_sdsdot.c
 *
 * The program is a C interface to sdsdot.
 * It calls the fortran wrapper before calling sdsdot.
 *
 * Written by Keita Teranishi.  2/11/1998
 *
 */
#include "cblas.h"
#include "cblas_f77.h"
float cblas_sdsdot( const int N, const float alpha, const float *X,
                      const int incX, const float *Y, const int incY)
{
   float dot;
#ifdef F77_INT
   F77_INT F77_N=N, F77_incX=incX, F77_incY=incY;
#else 
   #define F77_N N
   #define F77_incX incX
   #define F77_incY incY
#endif
   F77_sdsdot_sub( &F77_N, &alpha, X, &F77_incX, Y, &F77_incY, &dot);
   return dot;
}
```

I'm totally confused, why should this be done? Is it because Fortran is more efficiency in computing?

Comment: Probably there is some functionality implemented in Fortran and not in C...

Comment: Are you asking why is a Fortran subroutine called at all or why trere is a need for an intermediate wrapper?

Comment: I would guess `F77_INT` might have a different width than C `int`.

Comment: @beaker It is not that simple, there is an intermediate wrapper [`sdsdotsub`](https://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/da/de4/sdsdotsub_8f_source.html) which calls the [`sdsdot`](https://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d9/d47/sdsdot_8f_source.html#l00112) function. So I interpret the question as "Why bother with `sdsdotsub` and not call `sdsdot` directly.

Comment: @jxh However, that does change anything regarding the Fortran wrapper subroutine vs. the original Fortran function.

Comment: @VladimirF Ah... yeah, confusing question.

Comment: What I wanna ask is actually why there is a need for a intermediate wrapper, why not write it in C? @VladimirF

Comment: @VladimirF Since BLAS is implemented in FORTRAN, the calling conventions are apparently different. So the intermediate function uses a parameter to get the returned value via the FORTRAN routine.

Comment: @jxh But that concerns why there is `cblas_sdsdot` (written in C), not why there is `sdsdotsub` (a Fortran subroutine wrapper calling a Fortran function, but not changing any type at all).

Comment: @VladimirF `cblas_sdsdot` is a plain C function. `sdsdotsub` is a FORTRAN function. There is likely another abstraction layer hooking `F77_sdsdot_sub` to `sdsdotsub` that is not being shown. But, if the ABI is different for BLAS than for C, then it might mean the register that is used for return values in the C ABI is not the same as the register used for return values in the FORTRAN ABI.

Comment: @jxh There is just some name-mangling macro in between, if I searched correctly. Yes, fears of incompatible function result passing might be a concern although typically people ignore it (or used to in those days of pre-Fortran 2003). The (C) date is 1998 and by that time not many exotic platforms were still relevant, but perhaps some stdcall vs. cdecl issues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*"What I wanna ask is actually why there is a need for a intermediate wrapper, why not write it in C?"*

The whole CBLAS is a wrapper to BLAS. BLAS is defined using a reference Fortran implementation and **a Fortran API**. BLAS can be implemented in C or assembly, but the API is set to be Fortran.

Therefore the CBLAS does not actually contain the whole functionality. The functionality is in whatever BLAS implementation you install. The very common reference implementation is written in Fortran, but it is not the fastest one.

However, you probably could call the `sdsdot` function (in whichever language it is actually implemented) directly from C `cblas_sdsdot`. The author of CBLAS chose to implement a Fortran intermediate subroutine `sdsdotsub`. I do not have an answer why that is necessary right now. The difference is very small, really just changing a function to a subroutine.

As @jxh correctly comments, there is a larger risk of ABI incompatibility in calling a function vs calling a subroutine (similar to a void function).

Comment: Thank's a lot for the answer. While I'm not familiar with BLAS, what is the fastest BLAS right now?

Comment: @Sqr Hard to say. All of MKL, OpenBLAS, GotoBLAS (and probably some other) are fast. You have to make tests for your particular hardware, your particular compiler and the particular functions you will use most often.

Comment: OK, thanks again for answering my question!